# Discord.py ban Command Error: NameError: name 'client' is not defined

Tags: python, discord.py

I have attempted creating a Kick and ban command with discord.py, and it returns this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 58, in <module>
    @client.command()
NameError: name 'client' is not defined
 
KeyboardInterrupt

```

The code is this:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
  await user.kick(reason=reason)
  await ctx.send(f"{user} have been kicked sucessfully")
```

Thanks,
cassiecodes

Comment: The error you are getting is due to python looking for a variable named 'client' and not finding one. Without seeing your import statements or other code, we cannot provide much assistance.

Comment: In the part you are showing here, no variable named 'client' is used. Also as Matt said maybe your variable for your bot isn't 'client', maybe it's 'bot' or something but to help you we would have to see the function where the error occurees and the (probably) start code of your bot where the 'client' variable should be defined

Comment: @CassieCodes Can I please see your whole code once? I can help you with that only then.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't checked this in a while and I have actually resigned from the project. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score -1):

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
  await user.kick(reason=reason)
  await ctx.send(f"{user} have been kicked sucessfully")
```

Try using `bot` instead of `client`.

Comment: This will not work like that. You have to see first on how the bot variable was declared.